# Constant object list in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created the following array in my component:

```
private typesJobs = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Doctor' },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Nurse' },       
]
```

What I would like to do is create it globally to all components, as is done with models, but having that list filled when importing them into any component and that they cannot be modified, as if they were a constant list of objects

Comment: No clear, you mean you need to make it globally available in your all component where you can import typeJobs and use?

Answer (score 4):

put it in a file to export it (let's call it `types-jobs.ts`) and change the signature to this instead:

```
export const typesJobs = [ 
...
];
```

When you want to use it (import it) you would specify something like this:

```
import { typesJobs } from '/path_to_file/types-jobs';

console.log('jobs', typesJobs);
```

Comment: Isn't this still mutable?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz all plain javascript/typescript arrays are mutable. You could wrap the jobTypes in a function that returns a copy of the (private) data, but you would still be able to modify the imported array locally

Comment: I think using `Object.freeze(typesJobs)` as the return value of the function you suggested should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new service, name it something like types-jobs.service.ts, and your class will be named something like TypesJobsService.
inside the service declare and initialize typesJobs as private:

```
private typesJobs: any[] = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Doctor' },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Nurse' },       
]
```

inside the service again, create a getter for your typesJobs:

```
public getTypesJobs() {
    return this.typesJobs;
}
```

inside the component where you want to use typesJobs, use dependency injection and inject TypesJobsService in your component's constructor:

```
constructor(private typesJobsService: TypesJobsService) {}
```

finally you can access typesJobs in your component:

```
typesJobsService.getTypesJobs()
```